# Perform Tasks on Website Using JavaScript'

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation

I'm not sure if "automation" would be the right word to use but I'm essentially trying to make it so a script will log into a users account using their Auth Ticket then to perform certain actions on the website. I've looked around and the only thing I can find is Selenium, and I assumed Selenium was for testing purposes only and I need this running 24/7 so I'm not sure what to do. But I am trying to do this in JavaScript if possible.

Comment: you could use a headless chrome and a cron job. or just keep a tab open on your desktop and use tampermonkey to automate. i do that with a lot of sites, using canary to run it all so as not to interfere with my normal browsing.

Comment: @dandavis But I'm trying to have this running 24/7

Comment: i know, that's what i'm describing. if you don't want to manage node (headless browsers) instances in code, use PM2 or something. nothing stops a regular browser from running 24/7, so my "canary tasks" run all the time. you can use an old pc to run canary, or get a VPS to run node.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 24/7. should the browser never be closed? or should the browser redo the same action over and over again, but could be closed in between?